# MVC3 Entity Framework Displaying float type from database SQL Server

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am getting the following error when trying to retrieve float from database:

**The 'Hours' property on 'WorkHours' could not be set to a 'Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Single'.**

The Hours property in the WorkHours Entity is:

**public Single? Hours {get; set;}**

Table design type:

**Hours Float**

When i store a value it stores as a double(16 digits after the point),i believe float is 7 digits after the point.

Any ideas why i am getting that error?

Thanks

MVC3, EF4, Sql Server 8 (2000)

Comment: I think by default Entity Framework defaults to 2 decimal places precision (it truncates the rest). In Code-First there is a custom mapping method that can be used to set the precision on per property basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

The 'Hours' property on 'WorkHours' could not be set to a 'Double' value. You must set this property to a ***non-null*** value of type 'Single'.

```
public Single? Hours {get; set;}
             ^
```

Comment: That's what i have above in bold

Comment: @123456789 - It says you need a non-null type, and you are defining it as a null type.  Either make the table field nullable, or make your entity non-nullable.

Comment: Same error message. But i change to decimal on the model and database and works fine... so i guess i will use decimal instead of float

Comment: I have defined the field as nullable in the DB and I have assigned my variable as both **<nullable>single** and **single?**. This still produced the error for me. Any additional ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using attribute column ...

```
    [Column("latitude", TypeName = "float")]
```